# Selecting calendar weeks with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm looking for a possibility similar to the DatePickerDialog to select calendar weeks.

It is important that this also allows spanning calendar weeks (15-20).

The current rudimentary solution is a text field that the user fills in, but this creates a lot of potential for bugs.

Is there a way to modify the DatePicker accordingly? I haven't found much in the Android Developers documentation.

Final input should be possible in the format: 15-20, 23, 25-30. (representing calendar weeks)

Comment: What is that example data in your last line? Week numbers? Day-of-month?

Comment: What *exactly* is your definition of week? “calendar week” is meaningless. What is first day of week? Does week # 1 contain a specific day of week, or January 1? Are weeks always 7 days? How do you handle overlap between years in first and last weeks? Maybe [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) week definition?

Comment: @BasilBourque The example in the last line should represent spans of calendar weeks.

The ISO 8601 is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Working with ISO 8601 weeks has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. The *java.time* classes have some rudimentary support, while I recommend adding the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project for its `YearWeek` class.

Comment: As for user-interface, you’ll have to decide what is appropriate to your app and your users. You could show a regular date picker, and determine the week of the user’s selected date. You could show a list of Mondays’ dates. You could show a list of weeks in standard format of YYYY-Www.